# Mui input field resets while setting state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've recently been interested in material design and found a library called mui which is I guess basically a port of material ui to react. Everything is okay exept when I'm setting any state the fields resets.[image]

```js
import { FilledInput, Input, OutlinedInput, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import { alpha, createTheme, styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import MdEditor from 'react-markdown-editor-lite';
import Blog from "../components/Blogs/Blog/Blog";
import MarkdownIt from "markdown-it";
import 'react-markdown-editor-lite/lib/index.css';

export const AddBlog = () => {


    const [title, setTitle] = useState(""); //Setting this resets the text field


    const CssTextField = styled(TextField)({

        '& label': {
            color: 'white !important',
        },

        '& input': {
            color: 'white !important',
        },


        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
            '& fieldset': {
                borderColor: 'white',
            },
            '&:hover fieldset': {
                borderColor: 'white',
            },
            '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
                borderColor: '#0582CA',
            },
        }
    });

    const handleInput = (e : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setTitle(e.target.value);
    }


    return (
        
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-5 my-4">
                <CssTextField label="Tytuł" color="primary" className="md:w-1/3 w-full" onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)} />
               
            </div>

        


    )

}
```

Everytime stateful data changes the text input gets reset and the value also gets reset so you can't type in anything

Comment: Why aren't you just using `onChange={handleInput}`? since you aren't just setting the state from there.  Normally, you would only want to use the second style when you want to return/set the state immediately so like `onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}` and not a make a new function for it.

Comment: @SebastianGbudje I was testing it before with just that. Here's just an example of me trying everything I can. It doesn't work even with ```onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}```. Although I see that without CssTextField it works like a charm. I need the styles though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, yeah I found a solution to this. The reason was that whenever I set the state the component rerenders and so does the CssTextField variable. I moved the CssTextField out of the component and now it works. Here's the correct code.

```js
const CssTextField = styled(TextField)({

        '& label': {
            color: 'white !important',
        },

        '& input': {
            color: 'white !important',
        },


        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
            '& fieldset': {
                borderColor: 'white',
            },
            '&:hover fieldset': {
                borderColor: 'white',
            },
            '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
                borderColor: '#0582CA',
            },
        }
    });

export const AddBlog = () => {


    const [title, setTitle] = useState(""); 

    const handleInput = (e : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setTitle(e.target.value);
    }


    return (
        
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-5 my-4">
                <CssTextField label="Tytuł" color="primary" className="md:w-1/3 w-full" onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)} />
               
            </div>

        


    )

}
```